# Can't find Name in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular 6 and I am following Angular documentation with a testing project. Everything is working fine, but an error on console stopping me to create a build of the project The error is

> Cannot find Name "Hero"

[image]

Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
/* mock-heroes.ts */  

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Alex'},
  { id: 2, name: 'John'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Albert'},
];

/* heroes.component.ts */

import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HEROES} from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent{
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: '';
  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
     this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}

/* heroes.component.html */

<div>
  <h2>My Heroes</h2>
  <ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>{{selectedHero.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>Name:
     <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="Name">
    </label>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add an `import` for it at the top of your file, like `import {Hero} from `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the class file for the Hero is missing, You need to add import Hero from the path you have defined

```
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Alex'},
  { id: 2, name: 'John'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Albert'},
];
```

example

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

and import as ,

**`import { Hero } from '../hero';`**

Comment: Your Answer helped, But i am getting error while creating build. Type 'Hero' is not assignable to type ' " " '

Comment: change this line  selectedHero: Hero;

Comment: also import Hero there